# .NET C# Image Printing (Keep the quality)

Tags: c#, image, printing

I have some problem on C# Image Printing.

My requirement was:

1. Resize the image and print it out - (refer to attachment's image size)
2. But the quality shall not be drop - (refer to attachment's Img1, which is resize under microsoft office - using drag & drop)

   - for **Img2**, which is using C# code to resize
   - both output size was same but how can i achieve the result like **Img1**

Attachment Link: [Attachment](https://www.box.com/s/9zi1qii5z2u3mmxn8zvv)

Thank you... :)

Comment: I guess you'll  have to find an external imgaing framwork / component that has a better scaling algorithm than .NET. Suggestions anyone else?

Comment: which code did you try for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't without losing some quality, the best you can do in c# is:

```
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
}
```